# studies hard or hard studies

Tags: word-request

> Everyone admires her because she studies hard.

If I change this sentence,

> Everyone admires her for her hard studies.

Can I change the verb phrase "studies hard" into noun phrase "hard studies"'

Answer (score 2):

> Everyone admires her because she studies hard.

This means she works hard at studying whatever it is she studies. This is likely exactly what you mean to say. She is a hard worker.

> Everyone admires her for her hard studies.

This is awkward because it means her studies are difficult. The subject she chose to study is mind-bogglingly hard to learn. It doesn't mean she necessarily works hard at studying but that the subject itself is difficult. I imagine this is not what you mean, but if you do -- try to be clear.

**Everyone admires her for taking Quantum Mechanics because the course is so difficult.**

Or, On Edit: **"Everyone admires her for the difficult/hard course she chose.**